# querying XmL string taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

I have an XML

```
  <applicationbuilds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applicationbuilds" xsi:schemaLocation="https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applicationbuilds https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/resource/2.0/applicationbuilds.xsd" >
<application app_name="Architecture" app_id="15439">
<build   version="V 2.0" build_id="16158">

</build>
</application>
</applicationbuilds>
```

I use the below query to pick the appid,build_id and version from the xml using below query.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applicationbuilds')
SELECT 

   Y.ID.value('../@app_id', 'varchar(max)') as app_id,
  Y.ID.value('@build_id', 'varchar(max)') as build_id,
   Y.ID.value('@version', 'varchar(max)') as build_name

FROM @XML.nodes('//applicationbuilds/application/build') as Y(ID)
```

Although it works fine, it takes a very long time for the query to return result set. If i just avoid the line

```
 Y.ID.value('../@app_id', 'varchar(max)') as app_id,
```

it takes less than a second for the query to run. so the above line of code is causing the delay. What is the best way to fetch app_id without causing so much delay?

SQL fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19883
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many 'application' and 'build' elements there can be.

Only one 'application' element and one 'build' element:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applicationbuilds')
SELECT
    Y.ID.value('@app_id', 'varchar(max)') as app_id,
    Y.ID.value('(build/@build_id)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as build_id,
    Y.ID.value('(build/@version)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as build_name
FROM @XML.nodes('(/applicationbuilds/application)[1]') as Y(ID)
```

Many 'application' and 'build' elements:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applicationbuilds')
SELECT
    Y.ID.value('@app_id', 'varchar(max)') as app_id,
    Z.Z.value('@build_id', 'varchar(max)') as build_id,
    Z.Z.value('@version', 'varchar(max)') as build_name
FROM @XML.nodes('/applicationbuilds/application') as Y(ID)
CROSS APPLY Y.ID.nodes('build')Z(Z)
```

Comment: works like a charm! mine was the second case you specified. now it takes less than a second.. Thanks!!