# .Oracle xmlcast takes more time to provide the result

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle sql developer, adding the below two problematic columns takes much time (30 seconds) to provide the results as those two are defined as CLOB in source table. Without these two columns in select query data fetches in 0.8 seconds.

Issue is taking too much time to provide the results only when we include the below two problematic column's (30 seconds) and what we can modify to improve the performance of the query. Please suggest.

Full code:

```
select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ 
SYSDATE As curr_Date,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_value"]/value'))) as empl_value,
(fr.form_id||'/'||al.emp_id) AS emp_Reference_ID,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="emp_Id"]/value'))) as emp_Id,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="Institution"]/value'))) as empl_Institution_ID,
trunc(to_timestamp(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="emp_date"]/date[@format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]/value')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')) as emp_Date,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_type"]/value'))) as empl_Type,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="emplTrust_display_value"]/value'))) as empl_Trust,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_isFurtherInformation_display_value"]/value'))) as empl_Information,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_isConsentRequired_display_value"]/value'))) as empl_Consent_Required,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_AccessLevel_display_value"]/value'))) as empl_Access_Level,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_branchKey"]/value'))) as empl_Branch_Key,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_disclosure_branchSortCode"]/value'))) as empl_Sort_Code,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_branchName"]/value'))) as empl_BRANCH_NAME,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_branchPostcode"]/value'))) as empl_Branch_Post_Code,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_branchCountry"]/value'))) as empl_Branch_Country,
to_char(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(form_xml), ('/form/field[@name="empl_Assessment_other_desc"]/value'))) as empl_ASSESSMENT",
xmlcast(xmlquery('/form/field[@name="description"]/value' passing xmltype(form_xml) returning content) as clob) as employee_details,
regexp_replace(SRC.empl_feedback, '<[^>]+>', '') AS feedback,
E.EMPL_NAME AS EMPL_CD,
D.NAME AS empl_Unit,
al.empl_identifier AS empl_IDENTIFIER
from 
forms fr
JOIN table1 al ON fr.table_internal_id = al.table_internal_id AND AL.table_TYPE_ID in (1004,1003)
join table2 aln 
on aln.table_internal_id=al.table_internal_id
JOIN table3 SRC
ON SRC.table_INTERNAL_ID = aln.table_INTERNAL_ID
JOIN table4 d
ON Al.table_INTERNAL_ID = D.table_INTERNAL_ID
JOIN table5 e
ON E.table_INTERNAL_ID = D.table_INTERNAL_ID
```

Problematic Columns:

```
xmlcast(xmlquery('/form/field[@name="description"]/value' passing xmltype(form_xml) returning content) as clob) as employee_details,
regexp_replace(SRC.empl_feedback, '<[^>]+>', '') AS feedback,
```

Sample data:

All the columns we can put sample value as a string "a" and the problematic columns (employee_details and feedback) it can have more than (5000- 10000) chars.

Expected result:

Should complete faster instead of taking 30 seconds

Comment: And the question/issue is...

Comment: Issue is taking 30 seconds to provide the results only when we include above two columns in the query and if we exclude above two columns query output fetches fast.

Comment: can anyone please guide me on the above post.

Comment: Maybe: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237520/clob-varcharmax-is-causing-slow-select-query or https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2187062/clob-is-slow or  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536389800346757758  since we have so little to go on; I'm just looking at things others have considered.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It would be great if anyone can provide similar kind of solution provided in this link  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569907/querying-xml-string-taking-too-long)  seems like facing the same issue..

Comment: Consider updating the question with the fully query, sample data and expected results.  Havinga  complete picture may help people understand the problem better.

Comment: Thank you for the response. added the requested details with the full query, sample data and expected results.